# How to make autocomplete list in front of other components in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, autocomplete

I use a RootForm as the basic template for form page. There is one field associated with location autocomplete, so I wrap the native autocomplete of react-native and use it in that field. However, the autocomplete dropdown list is blocked by other fields in the form which are rendered behind it. I try to search online but no useful materials. Using modal or zIndex is not the solution here. How could I make the dropdown list on the top of other components even if it renders earlier than other components?

The following two snippets are my rootform and autocomplete render functions.

```html
  render() {
    const { input } = this.state;
    const cities = this.state.cities;

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
          data={cities}
          defaultValue={input}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ input: text })}
          placeholder="Enter Location"
          renderItem={({ cityName, cityId }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.listStyle} onPress={() => this.setState({ input: cityName, cities: [] })}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                {cityName}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />

      </View>

    );
  }
```

```html
    render() {
        const data = this.props.data;
        let fields = [];
        let onPress = null;
        Object.keys(data).forEach((key, index) => {
            let options = data[key].options ?
                data[key].options : null

            if ("type" in data[key]) {
                    fields.push(
                        <View style={styles.formField} key={key}>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>{data[key].label}</Text>
                            <AutoComplete />
                        </View>
                    )
            } else {
                let custom = [styles.formField];
                if (options) {
                    fields.push(
                        <View style={custom} key={key}>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>{data[key].label}</Text>
                            <TextInput value={data[key].value} style={styles.input}
                                readOnly
                                {...options} />
                        </View>
                    )
                } else {
                    fields.push(
                        <View style={custom} key={key}>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>{data[key].label}</Text>
                            <TextInput value={data[key].value} style={styles.input}
                                onChangeText={(text) => this.props.onFieldChange(key, text)}
                                {...options} />
                        </View>
                    );
                }
            }
        })
        return (
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView style={styles.container}>
                {fields}
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        )
    }
```

Comment: try react portals

Comment: @Maolei Tang Did you get any solution for this. I also facing same issue in autotag. My dropdown list is shown behind the Keyboard. Did you have any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your `style.container` to have a higher zIndex than whatever is appearing on top of it. However this will have the other items in the form appear behind the area reserved for the dropdown list, and render them unselectable.

If you want items underneath the Autocomplete component's area to still be interactive/selectable, you can use `React.useState` in order to have a dynamic `zIndex` property on your component.

```
const [componentZIndex, setComponentZIndex] = React.useState(1);
```

You will want your components behind the area reserved for the list to have a zIndex higher than 2 so that they are interactive.

Then you'll want to render your own input component so that you have access to the `onFocus` property. Luckily, the library you are using allows you to do this:

```
renderTextInput={() => (
    <View style={styles.input}>
        <TextInput
            onFocus={() => setComponentZIndex(999)}
            value={value}
        />
    </View>
)}
```

This will bring the list to the top whenever the user is using the autocomplete component. The last thing to do is to make sure that you push it to the back once the user is no longer using it.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', _keyboardDidHide);

    return () => {
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide', _keyboardDidHide);
    };
  }, []);

  const _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    setComponentZIndex(1)
  };
```